# Erro de relacionamento com Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Eu estou desenvolvendo projeto de teste que pretendo incluir no meu TCC, mas encontrei um problema ao relacionar duas entidades para criar as tablas na base de dados com o Entity Framework. São elas 'Post' e 'Comentario'

```
   public class Post
    {
        public Post()
        {
            DataPost = DateTime.Now;
            Categoria = new Categoria();
            Comentarios = new List<Comentario>();
        }

        public int PostId { get; set; }

        public string TituloPost { get; set; }

        public string SubTituloPost { get; set; }

        public DateTime DataPost { get; set; }

        //Post obrigatoriamente tem uma categoria
        public virtual Categoria Categoria { get; set; }

        //Post tem 0 ou vários comentários
        public virtual ICollection<Comentario> Comentarios { get; set; } //=====Comentários

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return TituloPost;
        }
    }
```

**classe Comentário**

```
    public class Comentario
    {
        public Comentario()
        {
            DataComentario = DateTime.Now;
            Post = new Post();
        }

        public int ComentarioId { get; set; }

        public DateTime DataComentario { get; set; }

        public string DescricaoComentario { get; set; }

        //1 Cometário pertence somente a 1 Post
        public virtual Post Post { get; set; } //=============Post

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return DescricaoComentario;
        }
    }
```

**classe de Categoria**

```
public class Categoria
{
    public Categoria()
    {
        Ativa = true;
        Posts = new List<Post>();
    }

    public int CategoriaId { get; set; }

    public string DescricaoCategoria { get; set; }

    public bool Ativa { get; set; }

    //Categoria tem uma coleção de Post
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return DescricaoCategoria;
    }

}
```

Eu tentei fazer o mapeamento de várias formas como apresentado neste post..: http://netcoders.com.br/mapeamento-com-entity-framework-code-first-fluent-api-parte-2/  Parte 2.

Porém de todas as formas que eu tentei ele cria as tabelas da forma que eu preciso, e até consigo inserir o Post, mas quando eu vou inserir um comentário ele da um erro de relacionamento.

Quem puder me ajudar eu agradeço.

***Edit***

**MAPEAMENTO**

```
public class MapPost : EntityTypeConfiguration<Post>
{
    public MapPost()
    {
        ToTable("Post");
        HasKey(x => x.PostId);
        Property(x => x.TituloPost).HasMaxLength(150).IsRequired();
        Property(x => x.SubTituloPost).HasMaxLength(300).IsRequired();
        Property(x => x.DataPost).IsRequired();

        HasRequired(p => p.Categoria)
            .WithMany(c => c.Posts)
            .Map(c => c.MapKey("CategoriaId"));
    }
}


public class MapCategoria : EntityTypeConfiguration<Categoria>
{
    public MapCategoria()
    {
        ToTable("Categoria");
        HasKey(i => i.CategoriaId);
        Property(d => d.DescricaoCategoria).HasMaxLength(60).IsRequired();
    }
}



public class MapComentario : EntityTypeConfiguration<Comentario>
{
    public MapComentario()
    {
        ToTable("Comentario");
        HasKey(i => i.ComentarioId);
        Property(d => d.DataComentario).IsRequired();
        Property(d => d.DescricaoComentario).IsRequired();

        HasRequired(x => x.Post)
            .WithMany(c => c.Comentarios)
            .Map(x => x.MapKey("fk_PostId"));
    }
}
```

**CONTEXTO**

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context() : base ("ConnectionString")
    {
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }

    public DbSet<Categoria> Categoria { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Post> Post { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Comentario> Comentario { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Properties<string>().Configure(p => p.HasColumnType("varchar"));

        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new Map.MapPost());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new Map.MapCategoria());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new Map.MapComentario());

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

**INSERINDO DADOS**

```
        var post = new Post
        {
             TituloPost = "Titulo Post 02",
             SubTituloPost = "SubTitulo Post 02",
             Categoria = new Categoria
             {
                   DescricaoCategoria = "Categoria de Teste 02",
                   Ativa = true,
             },
             Comentarios = new List<Comentario>
             {
                 new Comentario
                 {
                     DescricaoComentario = "Comentário Teste 01",
                     DataComentario = DateTime.Now
                 },

                 new Comentario
                 {
                     DescricaoComentario = "Comentário Teste 02",
                     DataComentario = DateTime.Now
                 },

                 new Comentario
                 {
                     DescricaoComentario = "Comentário Teste 03",
                     DataComentario = DateTime.Now
                 }
             }
        };
        db.Post.Add(post);
        if (!db.GetValidationErrors().Any())
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

**ERRO**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**OBERVAÇÃO**

O banco de dados que eu estou utilizando é o MySql.

Comment: Qual o erro?....

Comment: Dentro do construtor do `Comentario` você está fazendo isso `Post = new Post();`. Tira isso. O mesmo vale para o construtor do `Post`, tira essa linha `Categoria = new Categoria();`. Não tenho certeza se é isso porque não vi como você está tentando adicionar ao `DbContext` antes de chamar o `SaveChanges`, mas tenta aí.

Comment: Eu vejo um título como o dessa questão, me dá vontade de sugerir levar flores da próxima vez.

Comment: Coloque o código que você esta usando para salvar, e a mensagem de erro.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Eu editei a publicação com novas informações e o erro.

Comment: @Alisson eu cheguei a comentar estas linhas de códigos nos construtores e mesmo assim o erro ocorreu.

Comment: @CassioAlves eu coloquei o código e a mensagem de erro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo, vê se isso lhe ajuda, conforme esse código abaixo assim que você realizar a migration para o banco de dados as tabelas serão criadas da seguinte maneira.

[image: Banco de Dados realizado a migration Code-First]

> Classes

```
public class Pais
{
    public Pais()
    {
        Estados = new List<Estado>();
    }    

    public int Handle{ get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Sigla { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Estado> Estados { get; set; }      
}

public class Estado : EntityBase
{
    public Estado()
    {
        Cidades = new List<Cidade>();
    }     

    public int Handle{ get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Sigla { get; set; }
    public long PaisHandle { get; set; }
    public Pais Pais { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Cidade> Cidades { get; set; }  
}

public class Cidade
{
    public Cidade() 
    {

    }
    public int Handle{ get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Sigla { get; set; }
    public long EstadoHandle { get; set; }
    public Estado Estado { get; set; }        
}
```

> Mapeando as Entidades

```
public class PaisMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Pais>
{
    public PaisMap()
    {
        ToTable("PAIS");

        HasKey(x => x.Handle);

        Property(x => x.Handle)
            .HasColumnName("HANDLE")
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        Property(x => x.Nome)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(150)
            .HasColumnName("NOME");

        Property(x => x.Sigla)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(3)
            .HasColumnName("SIGLA");                              
    }

}

public class EstadoMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Estado>
{
    public EstadoMap()
    {
        ToTable("ESTADO");

        HasKey(x => x.Handle);

        Property(x => x.Handle)
            .HasColumnName("HANDLE")
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        Property(x => x.Nome)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(150)
            .HasColumnName("NOME");

        Property(x => x.Sigla)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(2)
            .HasColumnName("SIGLA");

        HasRequired(x => x.Pais)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.PaisHandle);

        Property(x => x.PaisHandle)
            .HasColumnName("PAISHANDLE");
    }
}

public class CidadeMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Cidade>
{
    public CidadeMap()
    {
        ToTable("CIDADE");

        HasKey(x => x.Handle);

        Property(x => x.Handle)
            .HasColumnName("HANDLE")
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        Property(x => x.Nome)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(150)
            .HasColumnName("NOME");

        Property(x => x.Sigla)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(3)
            .HasColumnName("SIGLA");

        HasRequired(x => x.Estado)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.EstadoHandle);

        Property(x => x.EstadoHandle)
            .HasColumnName("ESTADOHANDLE");
    }
}
```

> Classe Context

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext() : base("name=DefaultConnection")
    {
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }

    public DbSet<Pais> Pais { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Estado> Estado { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Cidade> Cidade { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //Aqui vamos remover a pluralização padrão do Etity Framework que é em inglês
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        /*Desabilitamos o delete em cascata em relacionamentos 1:N evitando
         ter registros filhos     sem registros pai*/
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

        //Basicamente a mesma configuração, porém em relacionamenos N:N
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

        /*Toda propriedade do tipo string na entidade POCO
         seja configurado como VARCHAR no SQL Server*/

        modelBuilder.Properties<string>()
                  .Configure(p => p.HasColumnType("VARCHAR"));

        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PaisMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new EstadoMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CidadeMap());            

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Comment: Jovem, isso não tem absolutamente nada a ver com o que foi perguntado.

Comment: @LINQ, Claro que tem, o problema dele está ao criar as entidades dele, ele nao está colocando as clunas ID para referenciar as FK, por isso está dando o erro. Dei um exemplo para ele como deve ser os relacionamentos entre as entidade e como configurar.

Comment: @NicolaBogar é necessário criar um identificador para a classe?  Vi uns exemplos com e sem os identificadores nas classes e dessa forma que eu fiz ele criou as chaves estrangeiras nas tabelas relacionadas da forma que eu esperava, porém ao salvar ele dá erro.

Comment: @EliseuMarcos, seria legal você dar uma pesquisada em DataNotations pois com ela você vai ver que na classe Entidade você configura o nome da tabela, o campo PK e os campos FK, ou pode procurar por fazer mapeamento como eu fiz ai com as classes PaisMap, EstadoMap e CidadeMap, pois você tem que definir qual classe é a PK ou FK por mais que ele já tinha criado no banco de dados corretamente. Faça um teste conforme o código que eu lhe mandei e veja se da certo.